# Authentication without username/password?

Tags: php, authentication

We are building a PHP multi-tenant application. Each company's account will run on their own subdomain  abcorp.example.com. The application allows companies to write and publish content (faqs, etc) for their customers to read.

They will tell their customers to visit: abcorp.example.com/ to read the content.  Or they will put a link to that URL in their secure web application.

However these companies may not want just anyone reading the content by going to abcorp.example.com/

So, the question I have is there any way to provide some basic authentication without getting into username and password authentication. I was thinking about some kind of hidden token added to the hyperlink or something like that

**My goal:**

1. If users type abcorp.example.com/ directly in the browser, they will not be able to see the web page because they didn't authenticate or pass the token in.
2. Avoid using username and passwords

Another option would be Referring URL Authentication

Comment: Do you have an example of a multi-tenant SAAS application in the real world that does this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use basic hashing whereby a shared secret password or "key" is stored on your system and each company system (a different key for each company and not published publicly), and then you hash the secret password with the subdomain in the link and include the digest as a parameter. Then you validate it by running the same algorithm on your side and compare to the digest.

the link might look something like

abc.example.com/?d=b5939ca22f5dcf345b4000641995478c5910dbd1607b1bdadcbf4a8618a95211

where digest is:

```
$d = hash('sha256', $secret_password.$subdomain);
```

or including the referer:

`$d = hash('sha256', ($secret_password.$subdomain.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));`

The hurdle to get over is making sure each of the companies can support the correct generation of these links based on the company specific key/algorithm - and that it is different for each company so one company cannot produce links for another.

It is better than no authentication, or a public shared token that is not validated at all, but I'm sure it still has vulnerabilities.

Comment: If a company bookmarked/stole the URL meant for another company? Then all of these is for nothing.

Comment: one point to note, when tokens are in the URL like this, they will likely be logged into the logs of web servers. This could make you vulnerable to leaking the tokens

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if someone makes the token public, it will open up access to whoever finds it.

I suppose each company could link to their page using a shared token, for example:

abccorp.example.com/?t=4rrfwr23rwads3

Each token could be stored in a file or a database.

When someone requests a page, it checks the value of $_GET['t'] with the one stored on the server. If it matches, it loads the rest of the page. Of course, this variable would have to be carried throughout the site, and included in every link.

Again, this will not be very secure. An exposed token could give access to the site to the entire world.

Answer (score 1):

Your "hidden token" idea is essentialy the way [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) work. A session can be used to identify a user (ie. keep track of what a user does as they browse through the site), and is [propagated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) either by passing the session ID along in links or by storing it in a cookie.

**However,** using a session without any other sort of authentication is inherently insecure! When you expose the way to authenticate and track users to the user itself, the user can modify or forge their authentication. For instance, the user could change the value passed along for the session ID or change the value stored in the cookie.

Please read the PHP manual section on [sessions and security](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php).

Answer (score 1):

Client-side certification. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the clients IP address as a token, giving different IP addresses access to different (parts / instances) of the system. But gain, this is not very secure, as

1. you have no way of knowing who is behind the client PC and
2. IP addresses can be spoofed. Perhaps you could develop additional specs; giving IP addresses only access during office hours, or check the clients browser (user agent) and check it against the user agent officially being used at the client.